# Creative Cloud is Using 25,744 ports -- vulnerable?

Tags: adobe-creative-cloud

When I run 'top' on my mac and sort by port usage, Adobe Creative Cloud is the top port user and is using ten times as many ports as launchd, the second contender for port usage. Does the application code follow best practice to secure each of these ports?

Comment: Are you sure they're all TCP/IP ports, and that they're open on an external interface?

Comment: I doubt it. There are only 11 ports displayed when I use `netstat -ap tcp | grep -i "listen"`   Would those 11 ports be the only ones vulnerable?

Comment: Vulnerable? No, they still wouldn't be.

Answer (score 4):

In TCP, using a port doesn't automatically somehow make you vulnerable to port scans. *Accepting connections* to that port does. If a program doesn't listen for incoming connections but only makes outgoing ones, the OS will already reject all packets not matching an existing connection.

(In `netstat -a`, sockets which are waiting to receive a TCP connection are in the "LISTENING" state. It's harder to tell with UDP, which is stateless.) But in any case, if a program *does* listen for connections, usually your home router and/or the OS come with a firewall which blocks them, so it's not an *immediate* worry.

But that's all besides the point, because [macOS `top`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html) **does not actually show TCP/IP ports.** (It would be an almost meaningless stat.) What it shows is *Mach* ports – an IPC primitive that's used internally by macOS software on the same computer, not over the network.

Answer (score 2):

are you referring to the `#PORT` column in top on OSX?

That is a representation of the running processes open mach ports, which are interprocess communications ports at the kernel level, these are not listening ports on the network.

try running `sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` to see what ports are actively listening on your mac.  I don't think you'll find 27000